# How to use Google Cloud's beta endpoints in node.js?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am sure the answer is very simple but can't find a definitive answer.

The Google Cloud Node.js SDK client libraries have APIs versioned in v1 (production), and others in beta, as mentioned in the documentation, for instance:

1. [google.cloud.vision.v1.CropHintsParams](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/google.cloud.vision.v1.CropHintsParams.html)
2. [google.cloud.vision.v1p1beta1.CropHintsParams](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/google.cloud.vision.v1p1beta1.CropHintsParams.html)

How do I code my requests to select a specific version ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can check this [vision api github](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision#samples). It has code samples for the non beta and beta version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Ricco D

`const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision').v1p3beta1`